# Commits reclaimed by others on git

Tags: git, merge, commit

I have committed something for my project (team project) and then team mate could not push items for some reason I do not know. Afterwards, he used "git merge" command and all the commits done by others and me renamed by his name.
So my commits now seem to be done by him. Can I reclaim my commits? What leaded this problem?

Comment: The team mate did rewrite the commits maybe

Comment: Without a detailed accounting of what exactly your teammate did, and what the current state of the repo is, there are too many possible answers to how to fix it.